# os.listdir command is not picking files in the correct storing order

Tags: python-3.x

I have stored files in one directory having order J_0.44105, J_0.44107, J_0.44109, J_0.44111. But when I load files by following code it doesn't pick files in correct order.

```
`df=os.listdir("folder")
for df in datafiles:
    print df`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns the file names in the order the files are stored on the file system, which can appear to be unordered. You should simply sort the list on your own with the `sorted` function:

```
for df in sorted(os.listdir("folder")):
    print df
```